# CQ5.6.1 where is the lucene configuration file?

Tags: lucene, aem, jackrabbit

I'm looking for the path of the lucene index configuration file in CQ5.6.1.
So where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `indexing_config.xml` file is embedded into bundle `com.day.crx.sling.server`. In order to change it, you need to extract it from the jar (see below), copy into `crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default` directory and reference in the `workspace.xml` file from the same dir:

```
<SearchIndex class="com.day.crx.query.lucene.LuceneHandler">
    <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
    <param name="resultFetchSize" value="50"/>
    <!-- this is the new line: -->
    <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="${wsp.home}/indexing_config.xml"/>
</SearchIndex>
```

Then configure Lucene indexing any way you want it.

**Extracting indexing_config.xml**

In order to extract the `indexing_config.xml`, first find the `crx-core-*.jar` file inside the `crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix`. On Linux/Mac OS X you can use shell:

```
$ cd crx-quickstart
$ find launchpad/felix -name 'crx-core-*.jar'
```

Then unpack the `com/day/crx/query/lucene/indexing_config.xml` file from the jar:

```
$ unzip -j FOUND_JAR com/day/crx/query/lucene/indexing_config.xml -d repository/workspaces/crx.default
```

Alternatively, you can download the `indexing_config.xml` [from Adobe site](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SearchIndexingConfig.html#indexing_config.xml%20from%20CQ5.5) and copy it to appropriate directory.